# position:absolute; is not effect one of the image

Tags: html, css

```css
.collection {
  margin-bottom: 20px;

}
.collection-content{
  position: relative;
  padding: 50px 143px;
  background-color: #F8F8F2;
  background-image: url("../img/collection-bg-img.jpg") ;
}


.collection-leafe-left{
  position: absolute;
  left: -150px;
  top: 40px;
}

.collection-leaves-right{
  position: absolute;
  right: -350px;
  top: 685px;
}


.collection-leafe-left-light{
  position: absolute;
  left: -216px;
  bottom: 170px;
}
```

```html
    <section class="collection">
      <div class="container">
        <div class=" collection-content ">
          

          <img class="collection-leafe-left" src="https://via.placeholder.com/371 " alt width="371" height="371" >

            <img class="collection-leaves-right" src="https://via.placeholder.com/546/592?text=POSITION+IS+NOT+WORKING

C/O https://placeholder.com/ " alt  width="546" height="592" >

          <img class="collection-leafe-left-light" src="https://via.placeholder.com/314" alt width="314" height="287"  >
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

[image]

position:absolute; is not working with collection-right-mix image. Why is that so?

Because of position:absolute; is not working with collection-right-mix image , appear scroll across horizontal.
How to effect position to the collection-right-mix image

Comment: Can we have your code.

Answer (score 0):

### Change `padding` to `margin` for `.collection-content`

`position: absolute` considers the `padding` part of the `width`.

Thus, `.collection-content {  padding: 50px 143px;  }` would position the absolute children the same as `.collection-content {  padding: 0;  }`.

On the other hand, `position: absolute` does NOT consider the `margin` part of the `width`.

So now, the absolutely position children should be positioned as you desired.

```css
.collection {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.collection-content {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px 143px; /* Changed */
  background-color: #F8F8F2;
  background-color: #ccc; /* Changed */
  background-image: url("../img/collection-bg-img.jpg");
}

.collection-leafe-left {
  position: absolute;
  left: -150px;
  top: 40px;
}

.collection-leaves-right {
  position: absolute;
  right: -350px;
  top: 685px;
}

.collection-leafe-left-light {
  position: absolute;
  left: -216px;
  bottom: 170px;
}
```

```html
<section class="collection">
  <div class="container">
    <div class=" collection-content ">
      <img class="collection-leafe-left" src="https://via.placeholder.com/371 " alt width="371" height="371">

      <img class="collection-leaves-right" src="https://via.placeholder.com/546/592?text=POSITION+IS+NOT+WORKING" alt width="546" height="592">

      <img class="collection-leafe-left-light" src="https://via.placeholder.com/314" alt width="314" height="287">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```